# Can Mysql Select Into Write Column Headers?

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to write column headers into my csv files, and cannot figure out how, using `select .. into` syntax.

I've visited this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html), as well as looking at some SO posts on the subject. I am wondering if MySQL's `select .. into` provides a feature to write the column headers or if there's another way to do that, while still writing a .csv file. A plain select at the command line does write the column headers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include headers when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile)

Comment: This should be closed. It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile I voted to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ugly, but solves your proble,

```
select * INTO OUTFILE from (
select 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
UNION ALL
select col1, col2, col3 from table_name) as t
```