# how to take periodically database script backup using event in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to take database script backup every day using event in mySql ..I am new to mySql , so unable to find out exact solution..can anybody help me to do so??
Tried it using mysqldump utility but it is command promt oriented , i want it to be done through event scheduler only.

```
DELIMITER $$
create  EVENT `Backup` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute
STARTS '2016-02-25 17:08:06' ON COMPLETION  PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
BEGIN
SET @sql_text = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM purpleaid INTO OUTFILE '/C:/Users/Admin123/Desktop/db/" , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d') , "db.csv'" ); 
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text; 
EXECUTE s1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

tried this , but its for single table only.I want complete database script

Comment: You can try backing up the database by using mysqldump and then using a cron job to schedule it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [information_schema.tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) table to get list of tables within a database, and [information_schema.columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) table to get list of columns (just in case you want to have column names included in the backup files).

1. Create a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) by getting all table names from your database
2. Loop through the cursor and get the table name into a variable
3. Construct your `select ... into outfile ...` statements the same way as you do in your current code, just add the table name from the variable.
4. Execute the prepared statement.

If you want to add the column names dynamically to the output, then combine Joe's and matt's answers from [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile).

UPDATE

For views, stored procedures, functions, and triggers (and tables, for that matter) the issue is that you can't really interact with [`show create ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show.html) statements' results within sql. You can try to recreate their definitions from their respective [information_schema tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html), but as far as I know, it is not possible to fully reconstruct each object just based on these tables. You need to use an external tool for that, such us mysqldump. If you want a full backup option, then you would be a lot better off, if you used an external tool, that is scheduled by the OS' task scheduler.

Since table structures and other database objects do not change that often (at least, not in production), you can use external tool to back up the structure and use the internal scheduled script to regularly back up the contents.

Comment: Well, you should have been a lot clearer in your original question what you are after. I updated my answer, but you are not going to like it.