# How to specify column name for MySQL select query out file?

Tags: mysql

nohup mysql -uroot drdb -e "select c_imei as IMEI, c_last_seen_imsi as IMSI, c_msisdn as MSISDN from tb_e A, tb_m B where A.c_last_seen_imsi=B.c_imsi into outfile '/apps/duinfo.txt';" &

In the above command, I can see the out file generated. But the column name is not specified. How do I specify column name for the out file?

NB: The answer to the question "Include headers when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?" didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include headers when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile)

Comment: That didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: It cannot fail to work show me the query with the union clause.

Comment: Why use union here? Could you please edit my command with the union clause?

Comment: That's explained in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the column name may not appear on top due to order of the resultset, so try creating a dummy column and order the output against it for a consistent result. Try the query below instead

```
 SELECT IMEI,IMSI,MSISDN FROM
  (select '1' as dummy_col, 'IMEI'as IMEI, 'IMSI' as IMSI, 'MSISDN' as MSISDN
  UNION ALL
  select '2' as dummy_col, c_imei as IMEI, c_last_seen_imsi as IMSI, c_msisdn as MSISDN from tb_e A, tb_m B where A.c_last_seen_imsi=B.c_imsi) ORDER BY dummy_col
```