# column names not getting exported into csv but data does

Tags: mysql, pdo

everything seems to work in the following code as in it does download data from the table but the column names are not showing in the csv what is wrong?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from interviews");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$filename = "export.csv";

$f = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

header('Content-Type: text/csv');

header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="export.csv"');

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");

foreach ($rows as $line) { 
    fputcsv($f, $line); 
}

fclose($f);
```

Thanks

Comment: ' what is wrong' - nothing- thats what it does , union headers

Comment: how do i get the column names also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include headers when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile)

Comment: it is fetching all the user submitted data just that the column names are not getting printed is what i am saying

Comment: its just showing the data without any header names

Comment: I get that what don't you get about using select data..union select headers ?

Comment: nevermind got it sorted