# How to export table with its attribute names?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to  output query result into a csv file

```
select*from  fileName INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\ans.csv' 
columns terminated by ',' lines terminated by ',\n' ;
```

It is working fine but it is exporting the data I want to export data with attribute names.How to do that.

`Example of EXPECTED OUTPUT` I want data to be exported along with ID NAME AND CLASS.

```
 ID   NAME   CLASS
 1    AB     d3
 2    cc     d4
 3    ff     g8

What I am getting!1 
 1    AB     d3
 2    cc     d4
 3    ff     g8
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile

Comment: See, particularly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13603727/5790584).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT 'Name',
       'CLASS'
UNION ALL
SELECT Name,
       CLASS
FROM fileName INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\ans.csv' columns terminated BY ',
                                                                                        ' lines terminated BY ',\n'
```

Comment: We have to hard code it?

Comment: Yes I think . I don't know any other way.

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard instead of query ?

Comment: I don't want to do this manually again and again !!

Comment: @Arsalan Valoojerdi - OP is not using sqlserver